# Do I need to be Administrator to set TFS 2010 alert

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Someone in my team try to subscribe to TFS alert when an items is assigned to her or remove from her. When she open the "Project Alert" panel, she can check all alert, except the first one, which is the only one she want!

[image]

The only thing I found is [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181335(v=vs.90)) telling this :

> "To perform these procedures, you must be a member of the Readers group or have the View project-level information permission set to Allow. For more information, see Team Foundation Server Permissions."

Her TFS permission are all right.

I'm asking myself if she need to be Administrator of is machine to be able to set this particular TFS alert.

Using TFS 2010 with Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the [solution](http://www.windows-tech.info/4/b32d5d87aeaa7564.php)!

It's a bug! Just have to click to have the blue selection (like the image in the question) and then press the space bar.

So you don't need to be Administrator!

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to be an administrator on anything for that setting. Is the UI preventing you from checking the box? Are there any error messages?

Comment: No error message. When she click on the checkbox, nothing's happen.